# Flutter HLS (m3u8) format video from asset not playing on the iOS device

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, video-streaming

I'm facing a problem with the video player. `HLS (m3u8) video from the asset is not playing on the iOS device`. I've downloaded all the ts chunk files with playlist.m3u8 and copied them to the asset folder. Android there is no issue it's playing fine from the asset but on the iOS device it's not playing and the error log also not throwing.

Any solution? How to play HLS (m3u8) video from the asset/local on the iOS device.

Using:  `video_player: ^2.3.0`

***Thanks in advance!***

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access videos using HTTP (rather than HTTPS) URLs, you will need to add the appropriate NSAppTransportSecurity permissions to your app's Info.plist file, located in /ios/Runner/Info.plist.
See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsapptransportsecurity) to determine the right combination of entries for your use case and supported iOS versions.

Comment: @G H Prakash I've already added NSAppTransportSecurity permissions. But my question is different am not able to play HLS(m3u8) videos locally on an iOS device.  From the network URL, it was playing fine.